# How to fix my plot by showing the most representative x axis values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting some frequencies inside a pandas dataframe, thus I decided to use the `plot` functionality:

```
fig, ax = subplots()
df3.timestamp.value_counts().sort_index().plot(figsize=(25,10), colormap='jet',fontsize=20, kind='bar')
ax.grid()
```

[image]

However, since I have multiple timestamps my graphic looks like the above picture. How can I fix the x axis labels by just showing the most representative dates?

Comment: What does "representative" mean in this context? And [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is of course missing.

Comment: Have you looked through [The Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) to see if there is an example you could adapt? Like maybe in [Ticks and spines](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#ticks-and-spines)? ... From the Pandas docs - `The plot method on Series and DataFrame is just a simple wrapper around plt.plot()` : so you should reference the Matplotlib documentations for any customization/tweaks you need to make to your DataFrame plots.

Comment: This is most certainly a duplicate question, but with so many possible solutions it's hard to pick which one - a web search of `python matplotlib x axis dates overlap` should prove fruitful.